# How to autoreplace sql code

Tags: sql, oracle, replace, keyboard-shortcuts, toad

How to replace SQL code that is used very often using Toad for Oracle or Oracle SQL Developer?

Comment: more info please, example of starting point and expected results would be useful

Comment: I learnt it 3 days before.. now it is on stack overflow also. There is also another way of creating through code template. Code template is also used for replacing large code. It is worked with ctrl+space.

Comment: @davegreen100 More explanation added. Let me know if not enough.

Answer (score 0):

In Toad, go to :

1. **View**
2. **Toad Options**
3. **Editor/Behavior**
4. Select **Auto Replace**
5. Click on **Add**
6. In the new line created, add the preferred key under **Value** column
   and the code to replace with under **Replace With**.

**You can select how to trigger this shortuct by editing the **Activation expression** on the same window.

[image]

7. Click **OK/OK** and you are done!

***Example:***
if you added the letter 's' for shortuct as in the above image, type 's' in the editor and press the Space button. Letter 's' will be replaced with "select * from".

Usually **Space** button is used to trigger the replacement.

*{Used Toad for Oracle 11}*

For Oracle SQL Developer, use below link:
[Auto-Replace in Oracle SQL Developer?](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/02/auto-replace-in-oracle-sql-developer/)